# A List in alphabetical order going down not across?

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, height, width

I have a giant list that comes out of my database in alphabetical order.  It is placed in a Div with a set width.  I have each

floated left and the are all next to each going from left to right and its great.  BUT my client wants the order to go down not across.  So it is like this:

```
apple angry antler bone beard broken
```

She wants:

```
apple
angry
antler
beard
bone
broken
```

So if I do it this way I get a long list unless I make the height a set number, pushing the columns to the right, but then I run into the problem if the list grows and pushes out of the dimensions of the Div.

Is it possible to have a set height but once the list grows past the width it will push the height down ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `min-height`, which is not supported by all browsers (IE6). I would however recommend using a fixed height and setting the `overflow` to `auto`. That way your div will have a scroll when the list grows, but it will not affect your design.

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow: auto;">
    <ul>
        <li>apple</a>
        <li>angry</a>
        <li>antler</a>
        <li>...</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```